# How to mount a Virtual Hard Drive in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, virtual-drive

One of the features of Windows 7 is the ability to mount a virtual hard drive (from Virtual PC) as an actual drive within the OS.  What are the steps for doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://thelazyadmin.com/blogs/thelazyadmin/archive/2009/01/15/mount-a-vhd-within-windows-7-server-2008-r2.aspx

You go to Disk Management and select Attach VHD from the context menu.